# Use usb uuid as token for centralized 2FA server

Tags: token, uuid, two-factor-authentication

I looking for a 2FA centralized solution, on Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows, who can use Data USB key as token, for example using UUID device for the token. (I read it's not that much secure but for start it will be fine for us).

The idea is to us it for a user authentication at OS login and after on other web application.

I install LinOTP for try but I don't found a way to do it. The best should be a Open Source solution.

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the yubikey. It might be the most expensive solution, but it probably gets the job done, what you are looking for.

The yubikey 4 is a smartcard. You can simple create PGP keys on the yubikey and use this crypto to authenticate at your Linux login using `pam_poldi`. Simple and effective.

We also use the yubikey in HOTP mode and have initialized them with [privacyIDEA](https://privacyidea.org). I wrote a blog article, how you could [setup an enrollment stations](https://netknights.it/en/privacyidea-enrollment-station-for-yubikey-and-nitrokey/).

This way you can use the same device for offline local login and for authentication at webinterfaces (using HOTP).

**Note:** You only need a backend like LinOTP or privacyIDEA for using the OTP part. If you want to use local authentication like PGP, neither LinOTP nor privacyIDEA does currently support this.

**Disclaimer:** Please note that I was involved with LinOTP and am the project founder of privacyIDEA.